# ¿Cómo realizar una conexión a un web service?

Tags: php, xml, webservice, api

Soy principiante en los temas relacionados a las APIS y web services.

En este caso estoy realizando el web service para el apartado de frecuencia/cotizador de la paqueteria ESTAFETA con PHP, con el fin de incrustarlo en mi ecommerce.

Entiendo la estructura del (xml) los parámetros que conlleva, mas no se cómo realizar la conexión a la url de producción que proporcionan.

La url que corresponde a producción es la siguiente:

http://frecuenciacotizador.estafeta.com/Service.asmx

Y el xml de ejemplo de petición al web service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:est="http://www.estafeta.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<est:FrecuenciaCotizador>
<est:idusuario>1</est:idusuario>
<!--Optional:-->
<est:usuario>User</est:usuario>
<!--Optional:-->
<est:contra>password</est:contra>
<est:esFrecuencia>true</est:esFrecuencia>  Solo Frecuencia
<est:esLista>true</est:esLista> El código postal origen y destino pueden
<!--Optional:--> ser Uno o Varios Códigos postales.
<est:tipoEnvio>
<est:EsPaquete>false</est:EsPaquete> El tipo de envío es Sobre
<est:Largo>0</est:Largo> Los parametros largo, peso, alto y ancho
<est:Peso>0</est:Peso> no serán tomados en cuenta ya que el
<est:Alto>0</est:Alto> tipo de envío es Sobre
<est:Ancho>0</est:Ancho>
</est:tipoEnvio>
<!--Optional:-->
<est:datosOrigen>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<est:string>01000</est:string> Código Postal Origen
</est:datosOrigen>
<!--Optional:-->
<est:datosDestino>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<est:string>62000</est:string> Código Postal Destino
</est:datosDestino>
</est:FrecuenciaCotizador>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Y el ejemplo de respuesta es el siguiente:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<FrecuenciaCotizadorResponse xmlns="http://www.estafeta.com/">
<FrecuenciaCotizadorResult>
<Respuesta>
<TipoEnvio>
<EsPaquete>false</EsPaquete>El valor false indica que el tipo de envio es sobre
<Largo>0</Largo>
<Peso>0</Peso>
<Alto>0</Alto>
<Ancho>0</Ancho>
</TipoEnvio>
<TipoServicio>
<TipoServicio>
<DescripcionServicio>9:45</DescripcionServicio> Servicio 9:45
<TipoEnvioRes>0</TipoEnvioRes>
<AplicaCotizacion>No</AplicaCotizacion>
<TarifaBase>0</TarifaBase>
<CCTarifaBase>0</CCTarifaBase>
<CargosExtra>0</CargosExtra>
<SobrePeso>0</SobrePeso>
<CCSobrePeso>0</CCSobrePeso>
<CostoTotal>0</CostoTotal>
<Peso>0</Peso>
<AplicaServicio>Si</AplicaServicio>
</TipoServicio>
<TipoServicio>
<DescripcionServicio>11:30</DescripcionServicio>
<TipoEnvioRes>0</TipoEnvioRes>
<AplicaCotizacion>No</AplicaCotizacion>
<TarifaBase>0</TarifaBase>
<CCTarifaBase>0</CCTarifaBase>
<CargosExtra>0</CargosExtra>
<SobrePeso>0</SobrePeso>
<CCSobrePeso>0</CCSobrePeso>
<CostoTotal>0</CostoTotal>
<Peso>0</Peso>
<AplicaServicio>Si</AplicaServicio>
</TipoServicio>
<TipoServicio>
<DescripcionServicio>Dia Sig.</DescripcionServicio>
<TipoEnvioRes>0</TipoEnvioRes>
<AplicaCotizacion>No</AplicaCotizacion>
<TarifaBase>0</TarifaBase>
<CCTarifaBase>0</CCTarifaBase>
<CargosExtra>0</CargosExtra>
<SobrePeso>0</SobrePeso>
<CCSobrePeso>0</CCSobrePeso>
<CostoTotal>0</CostoTotal>
<Peso>0</Peso>
<AplicaServicio>Si</AplicaServicio>
</TipoServicio>
<TipoServicio>
<DescripcionServicio>2 Dias</DescripcionServicio>
<TipoEnvioRes>0</TipoEnvioRes>
<AplicaCotizacion>No</AplicaCotizacion>
<TarifaBase>0</TarifaBase>
<CCTarifaBase>0</CCTarifaBase>
<CargosExtra>0</CargosExtra>
<SobrePeso>0</SobrePeso>
<CCSobrePeso>0</CCSobrePeso>
<CostoTotal>0</CostoTotal>
<Peso>0</Peso>
<AplicaServicio>Si</AplicaServicio>
</TipoServicio>
<TipoServicio>
<DescripcionServicio>Terrestre</DescripcionServicio>
<TipoEnvioRes>0</TipoEnvioRes>
<AplicaCotizacion>No</AplicaCotizacion>
<TarifaBase>0</TarifaBase>
<CCTarifaBase>0</CCTarifaBase>
<CargosExtra>0</CargosExtra>
<SobrePeso>0</SobrePeso>
<CCSobrePeso>0</CCSobrePeso>
<CostoTotal>0</CostoTotal>
<Peso>0</Peso>
<AplicaServicio>Si</AplicaServicio>
</TipoServicio>
</TipoServicio>
<Colonias>
<Colonias>
<string>CUERNAVACA CENTRO</string>
</Colonias>
</Colonias>
<ModalidadEntrega>
<OcurreForzoso>No</OcurreForzoso>
<Frecuencia>Semanal</Frecuencia>
</ModalidadEntrega>
<DiasEntrega>
<Lunes>X</Lunes>
<Martes>X</Martes>
<Miercoles>X</Miercoles>
<Jueves>X</Jueves>
<Viernes>X</Viernes>
<Sabado>X</Sabado>
<Domingo></Domingo>
</DiasEntrega>
<CostoReexpedicion>No</CostoReexpedicion>
<ExistenteSiglaOri>Si</ExistenteSiglaOri>
<ExistenteSiglaDes>Si</ExistenteSiglaDes>
<Destino>
<CpDestino>62000</CpDestino>
<Plaza1>Cuernavaca</Plaza1>
<Municipio>CUERNAVACA</Municipio>
<Estado>MORELOS</Estado>
</Destino>
<Error>000</Error>
<MensajeError/>
<CodigoPosOri>01000</CodigoPosOri>
</Respuesta>
</FrecuenciaCotizadorResult>
</FrecuenciaCotizadorResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

¿Alguien podría orientarme un poco sobre el tema?

Comment: Hay un buen ejemplo en [esta liga](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/986637-como-y-donde-insertar-codigo-php/).

Answer (score 1):

Esto puedes hacerlo mediante SOAP:

En la ruta es necesario poner ?wsdl

```
        $soapClient = new SoapClient("https://soapserver.example.com/blahblah.asmx?wsdl"); 

        // Prepare SoapHeader parameters 
        $sh_param = array( 
                    'Username'    =>    'username', 
                    'Password'    =>    'password'); 
        $headers = new SoapHeader('http://soapserver.example.com/webservices', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param); 

        // Prepare Soap Client 
        $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers)); 

        // Setup the RemoteFunction parameters 
        $ap_param = array( 
                    'amount'     =>    $irow['total_price']); 

        // Call RemoteFunction () 
        $error = 0; 
        try { 
            $info = $soapClient->__call("RemoteFunction", array($ap_param)); 
        } catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
            $error = 1; 
            print(" 
            alert('Sorry, blah returned the following ERROR: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring.". We will now take you back to our home page.'); 
            window.location = 'main.php'; 
            "); 
        } 

        if ($error == 0) {        
            $auth_num = $info->RemoteFunctionResult; 

            if ($auth_num < 0) { 
                .... 

                // Setup the OtherRemoteFunction() parameters 
                $at_param = array( 
                            'amount'        => $irow['total_price'], 
                            'description'    => $description); 

                // Call OtherRemoteFunction() 
                $trans = $soapClient->__call("OtherRemoteFunction", array($at_param)); 
                $trans_result = $trans->OtherRemoteFunctionResult; 
            .... 
                } else { 
                    // Record the transaction error in the database 

                // Kill the link to Soap 
                unset($soapClient); 
            } 
        } 
    }    
} 

?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.soap.php

Comment: Fue de mucha ayuda, tu comentario, solo que tengo algunas dudas:
.-  en la parte de SoapHeader hay una url, honestamente no se que colocar ahi.
.-en segunda instancia en $ap_param se encuentra "amount" y mas abajo vuelve a aparecer junto con "descrption"
estoy algo confuso con esa parte por que no se donde colocar mis parámetros.

Comment: En SoapHeader es en caso de que tengas autenticación en el WebService y en el param es en caso de que entre a esa validación.

Comment: La autenticación no es por encabezado de Soap.